# Cargowise eAdaptor API manual + integration with QlikSense

Tags: api, rest, business-intelligence, qliksense

just wanted to ask, if somebody has a manual for eAdaptor API for Cargowise?

We are trying to get the data from the system to QlikSense via REST API and we are not entirely sure how to do it. We do have an URL that will get us probably to some "middle man", however we still need to create a query for a specific (for example) shipment.

If somebody was working with this API and would have some insight, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "eAdaptor Developers Guide.pdf" download which contains all the info about the CargoWise side of things.

You'll need someone with a CargoWise instance to download it for you from the following location in the CargoWise portal:
[image]